# perl assign regex match groups in while loop

Tags: regex, perl, hash, while-loop, match

I am looking for a shorter version of this code

```
my $s = 'test123abc456qwe789ghj999';

while($s =~ /(?<g1>\d+)[^\d]+(?<g2>\d+)/g) {
    my ($g1, $g2) = ($1, $2);

    #do s.th. with g1 and g2
}
```

I tried this, but it causes an endless loop

```
my $s = 'test123abc456qwe789ghj999';

while(my ($g1, $g2) = ($s =~ /(?<g1>\d+)[^\d]+(?<g2>\d+)/g)) {
    #do s.th. with g1 and g2
}
```

Or is it possible to get the matches as a hash in the while loop?

```
(
  g1 => 123,
  g2 => 456
)

(
  g1 => 789,
  g2 => 999
)
```

Comment: Your matches are already captured in the `%+` hash. For example, you could do something like `say $+{g1} * $+{g2};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your regular expression, you can use `\D` ( `any non-digit` ) in place of your negated character class. And you can directly access the named capture groups. You have to use the `%+` hash.

```
while ($s =~ /(?<g1>\d+)\D+(?<g2>\d+)/g) {

  # do something with $+{g1}
  # do something with $+{g2}

}
```

Comment: thanks, so it is not possible to assign the matched groups to scalars? like this `while(my ($g1, $g2) = ($s =~ /(?<g1>\d+)[^\d]+(?<g2>\d+)/g))`

Comment: See [Infinite while-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374107/infinite-while-loop-in-perl)